# Is sex a taboo subject in Lifehacks?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have asked [a question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2278/how-to-quickly-remove-stains-made-of-semen-from-clothes) about a problem which is somehow sexually related and there was considerable downvoting of this question without comments explaining why this happens. The question itself is not sexually related, but the problem in it has sexual ration.

At the beginning I was thinking it is not well formed question and a moderator helped me to edit it so that it can be more clear.

Something that surprised me were some comments about the nature of the question - they have told me this subject can be considered offensive for someone and people may not want to talk about this.

Should we avoid questions in Lifehacks with any relation to sex?

Comment: At first I thought it was a joke question like the one about hiding bodies. I didn't vote on it, but I could see people downvoting based on that assumption.

Comment: You might consider looking at [the meta Anime & Manga had similar to this](https://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21/is-discussing-hentai-allowed)

Answer (score 12):

#### No, it's not a taboo subject

Pulling some from [Shog's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86778/215485) on a related question,

> Stack Exchange is a diverse community, and *will* likely host discussions that not all are comfortable with... But there's a time and a place, and if the room you're in goes off-topic and offends, try to deal with that diplomatically ... talk to each other in real-time without resorting to overwrought posturing

The same can be applied to questions and answers. So long as the question or discussion is *on topic* and reasonably civil there's no innate problem in discussing things related to sex.

If there's a squabble between a few users who disagree with a particular post, they are free to leave a comment but should discuss it in a chatroom if there's going to be back and forth comments to avoid flooding the post. If some content is particularly offensive users have the ability to flag it for moderator attention and it will be handled accordingly. Otherwise, if some people just don't want to discuss the topic then *they can simply choose not to*.

Comment: Additionally, if we end up having a [sex] tag or some other tag that some people are uncomfortable with, they can choose to ignore it by editing their "favorite tags" on the homepage.

Comment: I did just edit that question to remove the sex tag. More than anything else, I can't see how the tag contributes to the question. The question is about cleaning, not about sex.

Comment: @JamesWebster I added this tag for people who want to filter  questions with any sexually related topics as proposed by  Shokhet in the above comment. You can enter this [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19798/lifehacks) to discuss this

Answer (score 0):

### Anything R-rated is off-topic

I think this falls under "Be nice". Why should we be okay with trying to offend people?

One bad apple spoils the bunch. If this type of question becomes accepted (even if uncommon), there are many users (including myself, to be honest) that *will* leave the site.

Comment: "Why should we be okay with trying to offend people?" Trying implies the person asking the question wants to offend people, but that assumption doesn't make any sense to me. Why would someone asking about sex be trying to offend people?

Comment: @Wipqozn Trolls are going to troll... But being deliberately offensive should be treated as a separate issue.

Comment: @apaul34208 Of course it should. I just don't see how having questions about sex means we're "trying to offend people" (aka being deliberately offensive).

Comment: @Wipqozn Do you know for a fact that a significant number of people out there will be offended?

Comment: @Mooseman I never suggested people would be, since I don't think most people will be offended. To be honest I'm not quit sure why you're asking me that. Did you mean to ask me something else, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Wipqozn I didn't say most. I said a significant number. By posting something which you know will offend a significant number of people, that is a violation of the "be nice" policy.

Comment: @Mooseman I'm still not sure why you're asking me this. Did you mean to ask me that people *won't* be offended, not will be offended?

Comment: @Wipqozn Put simply, I think posting questions of this nature is deliberately offensive to a great deal of this site's audience.

Comment: @Mooseman I understand that, I just don't understand why you're asking me to prove that.

Comment: @Wipqozn Because you said "I just don't see how having questions about sex means we're "trying to offend people""

Comment: @Mooseman You think that questions about sex are offensive for some people. Can you explain why it is offensive? Is this offensive for people whose culture has not accepted for normal to talk about sex or it is other type of problem? I just want to understand how this can be offensive if it is not directed to a person or group of people.